# Java: Syntax error on tokens, PrimitiveType expected instead - cannot cast enum extending interface

Tags: java, generics

I need to be able to pass a value returned by a function as a parameter to another function. And I can't figure out how to do it in Java.
I have

```
interface A {}
enum B implements A {}
class C {
  Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>> value;
  Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>> getActualEnumClass() {
    return value;
  }

  <T extends Enum<T> & A> T process(Class<T> clazz, Set<T> someValues) {
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't pass result of `getActualEnumClass()` to `process()`
Also, neither the following constructs would compile:

```
class C2 {
  Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>> getActualEnumClass() {
    \\...
  }

  <T extends Enum<? extends A>> T process(Class<T> clazz) {
  }
}
class C3 {
  Class<T extends Enum<T> & A> getActualEnumClass() {
    \\...
  }

  <T extends Enum<T> & A> T process(Class<T> clazz) {
  }
}
```

How do I pass the class returned by `getActualEnumClass` function to the `process` function?

Comment: This perhaps illustrates why it's a bad idea to use wildcard generic bounds in a return type (`Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>>`). `getActualEnumClass()` would return something that's any enum implementing A - without ever specifying it, but `process()` requires some specific enum type implementing `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to call `process(Class<T> clazz)` with a specific type inferred for `T` at compile time, then you can't count on directly passing as `clazz` the return value of `getActualEnumClass()`.

`Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>>` as return type of `getActualEnumClass()` is pretty much useless. You can of course cast the return type into a specific type in the invocation context (where you call `process()`), but this can also be done better without using wildcard return types.

Since you really don't have any means to enforce compile-time type safety for the return value of `getActualEnumClass()`, you can add a type variable to be used instead of your wildcard, but which can only be inferred where the method is invoked.

```
class C {
    <E extends Enum<E> & A> Class<E> getActualEnumClass() {
        return null;
    }

    <T extends Enum<T> & A> T process(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    void test() {
        process(this.<B>getActualEnumClass());
    }
}
```

Just note that inside `getActualEnumClass()`, you will have to cast the return value, and that will result in an unchecked cast warning with which you have to live.

In addition to that, note that the type witness in `this.<B>getActualEnumClass()` is only necessary when the argument is passed directly with the method invocation. It can otherwise be avoided by using an assignment context:

```
void test() {
    Class<B> cls = this.<B>getActualEnumClass();
    process(cls);
}
```

---

Now, if `this.<B>getActualEnumClass()` in your use case is unable to know about `B`, then you have an even bigger problem; this is because you don't have any type `<T>` available for the compiler to infer at `<T extends Enum<T> & A> T process(Class<T> clazz)`. If you find yourself in this area, please redesign your code. This is unlikely, though, because something like `B.class` is probably known in `test()`

Comment: I love the answer, but I can't figure out how to do that since the "actualEnumClass" should come from an instance variable as I clarified in the example and therefore I have those restrictions. Maybe if I can figure out how to overcome the variable limitation it might work

Comment: @Artem I guess that's why I commented about you having to live with an unchecked cast warning if you implement it like this. But are you sure you can't declare `value` without using wildcards? Beside that, shouldn't `C` be a generic class? `class C<E extends Enum<E> & A>{}` and `value` declared just as `Class<E> value`?

Answer (score 0):

if You are using `Class` just have to return class from `getActualEnumClass` and pass it to `process` method, something like this

```
 Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>>  getActualEnumClass() {
    
    return B.SOMETHING.getClass();
}

<T extends Enum<T> & A> T process(Class<? extends Enum<? extends A>> clazz){

    return (T)clazz.newInstance();
}
```

of course you have to handle exceptions as well

Comment: Hi @George Weekson I like your answer, but I wish it was that simple. I need basically to pass a type that is an Enum implementing an interface. And it is used in some places. I edited the question to add some clarification